# Different pixel values converting RGB to Greyscale using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I'm playing around with PIL library for image processing and testing the way PIL is converting an image from RGB to L (grayscale).

The image is butterfly.png from Set5

[image]

I load the image using Pillow like this:

```py
from PIL import image
im = Image('butterfly.png')
```

And convert it to grayscale like this:

```py
grayscale = im.convert('L')
print(grayscale)
array([[ 32,  45,  68, ...,  63,  60,  60],
       [ 27,  32,  40, ...,  60,  61,  60],
       [ 65,  35,  28, ...,  62,  63,  58],
       ...,
       [ 46,  49,  53, ..., 112, 114, 111],
       [ 46,  49,  66, ..., 115, 113, 114],
       [ 49,  53,  65, ..., 115, 113, 113]], dtype=uint8)
```

To test the formula that PIL uses, I see the documentation says:

> When translating a color image to greyscale (mode "L"), the library uses the ITU-R 601-2 luma transform: `L = R * 299/1000 + G * 587/1000 + B * 114/1000`

So I coded my own custom function:

```py
def pil_rgb_to_gray(im):
    R = np.array(im.getchannel('R'))
    G = np.array(im.getchannel('G'))
    B = np.array(im.getchannel('B'))

    L = R * 299/1000 + G * 587/1000 + B * 114/1000

    return L
```

And it returns a different result:

```py
grayscale2 = pil_rgb_to_gray(im)
print(grayscale2)
array([[ 30.372,  42.731,  64.337, ...,  57.696,  55.208,  55.208],
       [ 25.848,  31.278,  38.57 , ...,  55.18 ,  56.038,  55.18 ],
       [ 60.438,  34.392,  27.321, ...,  56.326,  57.799,  52.724],
       ...,
       [ 44.153,  46.429,  50.457, ..., 104.68 , 105.712, 103.071],
       [ 43.463,  46.647,  62.079, ..., 107.327, 104.968, 105.701],
       [ 46.397,  50.435,  60.725, ..., 107.327, 104.968, 104.957]])
```

Why am I getting different pixel values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with uint8 numbers in your array, which means they can overflow. This can lead to counterintuitive results because the order of operations matters where you might not expect it to. For example, there is a difference between:

```
>> # multplity (and overflow) then divide
>> np.array([200], dtype=np.uint8) * 587/1000
array([51.864])
```

and

```
>> # multiply by small number (and don't overflow)
>> np.array([200], dtype=np.uint8) * (587/1000) # note parenthesis
array([117.4])
```

If you wrap you fractions in `()` you should get better results.

```
L = (R * (299/1000) + G * (587/1000) + B * (114/1000)).astype(np.uint8)

# ...
array([[ 32,  45,  68, ...,  63,  60,  60],
   [ 27,  32,  40, ...,  60,  61,  60],
   [ 65,  35,  28, ...,  62,  63,  58],
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize adding the parenthesis makes a huge difference. Now if my array are float64 to begin with, would it mitigate the overflow problem from multiplication?

Comment: I don't think that will help with image data @StevenChen because you still have values spread over the entire range, When you multiply by a large number it will still overflow. Perhaps if you start with 8bit numbers and put them in a 64bit array, but that seems like the hard way to me.